# Using django custom permission on view defs

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have written a custom permission

```
class IsObjectOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if ...
            .....
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

And I am trying to apply this on a few particular view definitions.

## URLs.py

```
       url(r'^get_possible_moves/', include('GameView.get_possible_moves')),
       url(r'^get_available_pieces/', include('GameView.get_available_pieces')),
       url(r'^remove_pieces/', include('GameView.remove_pie

ces')),
```

## views.py

```
class GameView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GameModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer

    def get_available_pieces(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        permission_classes(IsObjectOwner,)
        ....
    def get_possible_moves(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        permission_classes(IsObjectOwner,)
        .....
    def remove_pieces(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        permission_classes(IsObjectOwner,)
        ......

    .......
```

But the permission is not working on the view and the permission doesn't seem to be getting invoked. I would like to know how to implement custom permission on view definition, any help is appreciated.

Note: There are other definitions too in this view, on which I do not want to impose the permissions. So, I cannot put the permissions at view level.
And this is not a game of chess.

Comment: Perhaps a method_decorator? [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

Comment: yeah, there is a method_decorator: `@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))`. But it might work only for function based views.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `permissions_classes` to the entire viewset and not just to the functions.

```
class GameView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsObjectOwner,)
    queryset = GameModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer

    def get_available_pieces(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        ....
        return
    def get_possible_moves(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        ....
        return
    def remove_pieces(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        ....
        return
```